# how to run mvn appfuse:gen-model without error?

Tags: maven

I'm using **appfuse** along with **Oracle db** and getting error whenever running command **mvn appfuse:gen-model**

Any Suggestion?

Comment: I think that depends on the error you get? And the version of the plugin you use. It may be related to https://kenai.com/jira/browse/OPENEMPI-63 ?

Comment: i don't know whether either having to provide the project with a hibernate.reveng.xml or it's optional. but after many warning(including [WARNING] Rev.eng. strategy did not report any primary key columns for XDB$RCLIST_V) it's error is as the following: Duplicate class name 'net.mycompany.model.AllFileGroups' generated for 'org.hibernate.mapping.Table(SYS._ALL_FILE_GROUPS)'. Same name where generated for 'org.hibernate.mapping.Table(SYS._ALL_FILE_GROUPS)'